# How to instantiate the result of a function that returns an extended class?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How in Jasmine test this code, method `getNumber`

```
const PageFactory = SuperClass => class extends SuperClass {

getNumber() {
.......
 }
```

I tried through `new PageFactory(null)` and `PageFactory.getNumber`, write

```
TypeError is not a constructor(evaluating 'PageFactory.getNumber()) or  _pageFactory["default"].getNumber()
```

Comment: Why is it tagged Jasmine. There's no trace of Jasmine in your source code and the problem seems to be Javascript related only.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`PageFactory` is a factory function that creates constructor.

```
class TestClass { // stub class

}

const Paged = PageFactory(TestClass) // create new class using stub

const pagedInstance = new Paged() // create an instance

pagedInstance.getNumber() // <-- test getNumber method
```